# When does Super Mario RPG Remake auto-save?

Tags: super-mario-rpg-2023

Early in the Super Mario RPG Remake the game mentions that there is a new auto-save feature. How often does the game auto-save?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is explained by Toad, but essentially every time you enter a new area the game will automatically save. In addition, auto-save is triggered when you rest at Mario's house or at an inn.

[image: Toad explaining autosaves]

Source, [Gamerant](https://gamerant.com/super-mario-rpg-how-save/).